# Adding content with Bootstrap framework

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have been studying bootsrap, and from what I understand, I just need to wrap my code with `<div>` elements of various classes.

I have built a webpage and now want to optimize it for mobile devices using Bootstrap.

Here is a portion of my code :

```
    <body onload="initializeCharts()">
    <div class = "container-fluid">
        <div class = "row">
            <div class = "col-lg-12">
                <div id = "header">
                    Sales Statistics for 2015 -16
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id = "page">  
            <div class = "row">
                <div class = "col-lg-6">
                    <div id = "quadrant1">  
                        <input type = "button" name = "zoomButton1" id = "zoomButton1" value = "Zoom" onclick = "zoomIn(this.id)" class = "zoomButtons" />
                        <select name = "chartType" id = "chartType" onchange = "changeChartType()" class = "chartControllers">
                            <option value = "nothingSelected">Select chart type</option>
                            <option value = "column2d">2D Column Chart</option>
                            <option value = "bar2d">2D Bar Chart</option>
                            <option value = "line">2D Line Chart</option>
                            <option value = "area2d">2D Area Chart</option>
                            <option value = "pie2d">2D Pie Chart</option>
                            <option value = "pareto2d">2D Pareto Chart</option>
                            <option value = "doughnut2d">2D Doughnut Chart</option>
                            <option value = "column3d">3D Column Chart</option>
                            <option value = "bar3d">3D Bar Chart</option>
                            <option value = "pie3d">3D Pie Chart</option>
                            <option value = "pareto3d">3D Pareto Chart</option>
                            <option value = "doughnut3d">3D Doughnut Chart</option>
                        </select>
                        <input type = "button" name = "chooseValuesButton" id = "chooseValuesButton" value = "Choose values" onclick = "displayChooseAlert()" 
                        class = "chartControllers" />
                        <input type = "button" name = "backButton1" id = "backButton1" value = "Go back" onclick = "goBack(this.id)" class = "backButtons" />
                        <div id = "chartA">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class = "col-lg-6">
                    <div id = "quadrant2">  
                        <input type = "button" name = "zoomButton2" id = "zoomButton2" value = "Zoom" onclick = "zoomIn(this.id)" class = "zoomButtons" />
                        <select name = "themeColor" id = "themeColor" onchange = "changeChartThemeColor()" class = "chartControllers">
                            <option value = "nothingSelected" selected>Select color theme</option>
                            <option value = "#FFFF00">Yellow and White</option>
                            <option value = "#D80000">Red and White</option>
                            <option value = "#0000CC">Blue and White</option>
                            <option value = "#006600">Green and White</option>
                        </select>
                        <input type = "button" name = "backButton2" id = "backButton2" value = "Go back" onclick = "goBack(this.id)" class = "backButtons" />
                        <div id = "chartB">
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

When I run this on my browser, I see that the columns render at the ends of the page, not like the half columns that I want. When the browser is resized to mobile size, I want the quadrant divs to come one below the other, but on 
desktops I want the quadrant divs to occupy half the width of the screen.

What is wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lays in the size of your columns you've set.

You are using the large column that breaks immediately when you leave the large viewport. `.col-lg-6` should be changed to `.col-md-6` or `.col-sm-6` in order to keep those two columns together for a little longer.

Using `.col-xs-6` creates the column "unbreakable" since it does not drop even on mobile device. Otherwise your code seems to be all right, and if I understood the question correctly, this is what you are asking. Correct me if I'm wrong and clearify your question a bit! :)

Comment: And for the whole page being used, change `.container-fluid` to `.container` or wrap the content inside the fluid container to plain container to keep it kind of centralized.

Answer (score -1):

Bootstrap file add in html file to boot strep use in php.

```
<script src="filename.js"></script>
```

And add particular file add in folder.